# convert raw postgresql query to cypher query

Tags: neo4j

I have raw SQL query. I want to convert it into cypher query.

```
select name, count(country) from public.mytable where country in ('Nigeria', 'Sweden') group by country, name
```

I was written query in cypher but doesn't return anything. But raw SQL query return the results.

```
match (m:mytable) where m.country=all[c in ['Nigeria', 'Sweden'] where c in m] return m.country, m.name
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cypher, aggregation is implicit and is mostly done using `WITH` clause, or in the `RETURN` statement. Try this:

```
match (m:mytable) where m.country IN ['Nigeria', 'Sweden'] 
WITH m.country AS country, m.name AS name, count(m.country) AS countryCount
RETURN name, countryCount
```

Comment: There is a typo error on variable `country` not defined.